# Add tag to post api wordpress

Tags: posts, tags

I have been googling around but could not find the "add tag to post" api/codex. Does anyone know what it is ? Also, the "delete tag from post".

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about external api-requests like XML-RPC or the WordPress-api for adding/deleting tags to posts?

Comment: Looking for the "wp_function" function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find an index of a good chunk of the WordPress API [here on codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference). The function you want is [wp_set_post_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags), but follow the links from that page to related functions.

Edit: this should remove a tag from a post, per comment below

```
// $post is your post object, e.g. from: global $post;
// $target is tag you want to remove

// get an array of current tags on post
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID, array('fields' => 'names'));

// remove selected tag from array
$key = array_search($target, $tags);
if ($key !== false) {
    unset($tags[$key]);
}

// set new list of tags, without $target
wp_set_post_tags($post->ID, $tags, false);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Just what I needed to know. Is there a way to delete/unset a tag from a post ? But not from the terms pool.

Comment: @PrakashRaman: please see updated answer

Answer (score 6):

You would use the [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) function to insert a new tag:

```
wp_insert_term( 'post_tag', 'happy' );
```

Then after creating your terms, you would add them to the post of your choice using the [`wp_set_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) function, like so:

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'happy', 'post_tag', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Knows it.

If you wanted to add a categories to a post with the ID of 42:

```
$cat_ids = array( 6,8 );
    //to make sure the terms IDs is integers:
    //$cat_ids = array_map('intval', $cat_ids);
    //$cat_ids = array_unique( $cat_ids );
wp_set_object_terms( '42', $cat_ids, 'category' );
```

If you wanted to clear/remove all categories from a post with the ID of 42:

```
wp_set_object_terms( '42', NULL, 'category' );
```

read more about [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

Comment: thanks, but am looking for setting tags to a post.

Comment: @PrakashRaman This will set tags to a post. Just replace `category` with `post-tag`.

Comment: Basicly its example from page that overyone here referenceing... category is same term as post_tag just hierarchical one. take a look to any of links posted here (anyway thay all points to one place)...